# Block Django Urls to Users

Tags: django, reactjs

**I'm new to django and making a project on django and react**

React has all the frontend code and django has all the REST api. I am using axios to make GET or POST request.
The django urls has views to save the data or retrieve the data.

Now the problem is, I do not want the user to access the django urls, they must be used only by **axios**.

For example:
If this is my url
`path(r'^contactform/contact/',ContactView.as_view())`

and you visit it on browser
`http://localhost:8000/contactform/contact/`
it shows a django-rest-framework's ListCreateAPIView as I used it.

I want to redirect user to a template or show an error page.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the `request.is_ajax()` check.

For example, in a view:

```
@login_required()
def my_ajax_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
       # do something
    else:
      return HttpBadRequest() # or some other error or redirect
```

However, in order for this to work, Axios needs to set the X-Requested-With header in its requests, then you will be able to use that header to detect AJAX calls.

In the Axios request config:

```
{
   headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
   ...
}
```

That's assuming Axios hasn't built that header into a more recent version that I'm not aware of.

To make this easier, you can create a custom decorator as well:

In decorators.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest

def ajax_required(f):
    """
    AJAX request required decorator

    """    
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.is_ajax():
                return HttpResponseBadRequest()
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__=f.__doc__
    wrap.__name__=f.__name__
    return wrap
```

Then in your view:

```
from decorators import ajax_required

@ajax_required
@login_required
def my_ajax_view(request):
    #do something
```

Or if you are using class-based views:

```
class MyAjaxView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'template.html'

    @method_decorator(ajax_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```